# necesito ayuda con botones creados dinámicamente desde programación en swift

Tags: ios, swift, programación-móvil

lo que tengo hasta este momento, es que ya creo los botones, lo que hago es consultar una url y obtener un `JSON` que me dará la cantidad de botones que necesito crear, y todo bien hasta que les doy el target, cada botón debe tener su propio tag y cuando doy click a cualquier botón siempre se me sustituye por el ultimo y todos los botones quedan registrados con el mismo tag(el ultimo) dejo mi código espero haberme explicado bien.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    for(var i = 0; i < self.Categorias.count; i++)  
    {
        btnCategoria = UIButton()
        lblNombreCat = UILabel()

        if contador < 2
        {
            taged = Int(iidCategorias[i])!
            // Le damos Color de fondo al boton
            self.btnCategoria.setImage(UIImage(named: "planos.png"), forState: .Normal)
            // Radio del boton y otras configuraciones
            self.btnCategoria.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(20.0)
            // Generamos la posición (x, y, ancho y alto)
            self.btnCategoria.frame = CGRectMake(self.x, self.y, 50, 50)
            self.btnCategoria.tag = taged

            self.btnCategoria.addTarget(self, action: "siguienteVentana", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            let StoryBoardCategoria: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
            ProductosView = StoryBoardCategoria.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productos") as! ViewControllerProductos
            ProductosView.etiqueta = String(btnCategoria.tag)

            self.lblNombreCat.text = self.Categorias[i]
            self.lblNombreCat.numberOfLines = 2
            self.lblNombreCat.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)

            let size = lblNombreCat.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
            self.lblNombreCat.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xlabl-20, y: ylabel+50), size: size)
            self.lblNombreCat.textAlignment = .Center

            contador++

            self.x = 220
            self.xlabl = 220
            if contador > 1
            {

                contador = 0
                self.y += 80
                self.x = 45
                self.xlabl = 45
                self.ylabel += 80
            }
        }
        self.view.addSubview(self.btnCategoria)
        self.view.addSubview(self.lblNombreCat)
    }
}
```

no anexare donde me traigo el `JSON` porque creo que no es necesario.

de antemano gracias, espero su respuesta.

Comment: imagino que lo que te aparece en ProductosView.etiqueta es siempre el tag del ultimo botón, verdad? y debería aparecer el tag del botón pulsado?

Comment: es correcto mi amigo :$ y he intentado varias maneras y no logro hacer que funcione

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que en cada iteración del bucle le pasas al controlador el valor del tag cuando haces: ProductosView.etiqueta = String(btnCategoria.tag)
Entonces siempre aparece el ultimo tag

Lo que tienes que hacer es no llamar al controlador hasta que pulsen al botón y se ejecute el target, entonces ahí pones el tag

quita esta parte:

```
       let StoryBoardCategoria: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
        ProductosView = StoryBoardCategoria.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productos") as! ViewControllerProductos
        ProductosView.etiqueta = String(btnCategoria.tag)
```

Y deberías tener una función que se ejecuta en el target del botón:

```
func siguienteVentana(sender: UIButton) {
   //han pulsado el botón, llamo al controlador pasando el tag
     let StoryBoardCategoria: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
     ProductosView = StoryBoardCategoria.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productos") as! ViewControllerProductos
     //aquí paso el tag
     ProductosView.etiqueta = String(sender.tag)

     //deberías mostrar el controlador a partir de aquí, como no lo tienes no se como te vas a ese controlador

}
```

Y asi debería funcionar. Otra cosa que no haría seria utilizar el self con btnCategoria y con lblNombreCat, el ámbito va a ser el for y al poner self parece que es una propiedad de la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, lo que me faltaba era que en la función que llamo con el target no tenia los parámetros de 'UIButton' y yo mandaba a llamar la variable del botón

Comment: otra pregunta, espero no sea molestia, cuando mando el siguiente controlador no me aparece con el `NavigationController` , lo mando a llamar con `self.presentViewController(ProductosView, bool: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Eso depende de como quieras que se te muestre el nuevo controlador. Con el self.presentViewController lo haces de forma modal, lo normal suele ser que aparece desde abajo, se muestra, haces algo y lo cierras. Si lo haces haciendo un push al navigationController, suele ser el que aparece desde la derecha y luego tienes el botón del back para navegar hacia atrás. Investiga el performSegue para esta segunda opción